# Google Maps in Optimized RequireJS

Tags: google-maps, requirejs

Does anybody know how to include Google Maps in an optimized RequireJS file?

Using "async!" works fine in development, however when I optimise the project into one file it isn't able to load it.

I generally get "Error: No Async", which seems to tell me that the async plugin isn't in the built code, however it is defined in "paths" for the optimised build.

Comment: Fixed this in the end by migrating my project over to Yeoman and using their default Gruntfile, with the addition of some basic requireJS config.
`    requirejs:    
{dist:    {options:    {`
                mainConfigFile:'<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/config.js',
                out:'<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/main.js',
                name:'config'
            }
        }
    }`
Never really figured out what the true fix was though.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and cannot really solve it properly.

What I guess that solved your problem was that the Yeoman till recently loaded the entire require.js script in the build file as well. This does not work anymore since:

1. [usemin](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin) does not work anymore with `data-main` attribute on `<script>` tag
2. the entire require.js script is overkill for the production

The alternative for optimized code is [almond](https://github.com/jrburke/almond). I am still working on my Gruntfile how to use it properly and make the `async` plugin work.

Comment: In the end I actually used leafletJS for mapping, it's really worth checking out!

Comment: @AndyPolhill Yes, I checked it out, but it is not really the answer, just the other maps provider.

At the end the solution was that I include the minified and compressed version of RequireJS in the build file. The version with almond will not work as Miller expained in [this post](http://blog.millermedeiros.com/requirejs-2-0-delayed-module-evaluation-and-google-maps/).